# Find Model Not Found When ActiveRecordNotFound Raised

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a controller that calls `.find` on multiple ActiveRecord Models. I am using the rescue_from method to catch errors raised when records are not found. However, I am not able to find the type of the records that are not found. So suppose my controller looks like this:

```
class AccountController < ApplicationController

  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :handler

  def find_user
    User.find(params[:user_id])
  end

  def find_post 
    Post.find(params[:post_id])
  end

  def handler 
    flash[:error] = "{model} not found"
  end
end
```

The problem is I need to tell the user which record was not found, which would me {model} in the code above. Is there a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply handle it like this

```
post = Post.find_by id: params[:post_id]
flash[:error] = "Post not found" unless post
```

or you can pass a block to `rescue_from`

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do |error|
  # do something with error to recognize the model
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Equip your `handler` with the thrown exception, here param `exception`. Now you can use `exception`´s attributes `model` and `id`:

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :handler  

def handler(exception)  
  flash[:error] = "#{exception.model} with ID #{exception.id} not found"  
end
```